# ansible expect module respond to password prompt

Tags: ansible

I have read the documentation related expect module on [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html)

I'm trying to add a CentOS7 to 2012 AD Domain controller, here is my playbook,

```
  - name: Attempt to join the server to AS
    expect:
      command: realm join --user=admin@mydomain.local mydomain.local
      responses:
        (?i)Password for admin@mydomain.local: abc123
```

Ansible playbook fails, saying the password is incorrect, is this the correct way of using expect?

Comment: Looks good, but it might be best to fully quote everything on the line: `'(?i)Password for admin@mydomain.local': 'abc123'`. If you run the command with `-vvvv` can you check that you do get the required string?

Comment: This question has been on for a little while, I have used autoexpect a tool that comes with expect package to create an expect file, which worked perfectly with ansible playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to incapsulate the password in quotes like so?

```
(?i)Password for admin@mydomain.local: "abc123"
```